# How to save 'multipart/form-data' (picture, pdf, and etc.) to mysql database mediumblob via jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am building an assessment tool. The logic is:

1. In each question, once I click 'Upload/View Files', it will pop up a modal;
2. In the modal, there is a section you can select pic/document/video to upload. The code is as:
   [Html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqEvr.png)
3. Once you click submit, it will trigger jquery as below:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){   
       $('#upload_file_attachment').submit(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
           $.ajax({
               url: "ajax/upload-attachment.ajax.php",
               type: "POST",
               data: formData,
               async: false,
               cache: false,
               contentType: false, 
               processData: false,
               'success': function(data){
                               $('#upload_success_msg').fadeIn().html(data);
                               setTimeout(function(){
                                   $('#upload_success_msg').fadeOut("Slow");
                               },5000);
                           }
           }); //End of ajax


   })//End of submit


   })
   ```
4. And the following is ajax php code:

   ```
   require_once '../php-includes/connect.inc.php';
   global $db;
   $assess_id=$_POST['assess_id'];
   $quest_ref=$_POST['quest_ref'];
   $email=$_POST['email'];
   $type=$_POST['type'];

   if($type=="file"){
       $file=$_FILES["file"];
       $fileName=$file["name"][0];
       if(empty($fileName)){
           echo "No File Selected";
           return;
       }
       $fileType=$file["type"][0];
       $fileData=$file["tmp_name"][0];

   mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `files` VALUES('$assess_id','$quest_ref','$fileName','$fileType','$fileData', NOW(), '$email', '')");
   echo "Success";


   }
   ```
5. However, when I check database after uploading the file, it only upload the name like 'C:xampp   mpphpFE6F.tmp' into the blob, apparently the $fileData is not correct. Could you please help me how i can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please see tutorial here [PHP MySQL BLOB](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/)

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below one of the answers, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If none of the answers provided were helpful to you in resolving the problem, please add your own answer and select that as correct *(checkmark)* - you won't get any points for that, but it will close out the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to save your images to your server or something like [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com) and save the created link to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution, use this plugin:

http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php#doc

Ravishanker Kusuma has done such a good job that there is no point rolling your own. *(I am not in any way associated with RK, nor have I even communicated with him, but have used this plugin for years.)*

Alternatively, you can use his plugin as a learning tool / template and look at his code to see how he did it.